# How to create multiple threads using QtConcurrent::run()

Tags: qt

I tried running QtConcurrent::run() in a loop, but program crashes: (i am using libsmbclient)

```
void Scanner::scan()
{
    for(int i=0;i<ipList.length();i++)
    {
        QtConcurrent::run(this,&Scanner::scanThread,i);
    }
}
void Scanner::scanThread(int i)
{
int dh;
QString ip;
ip="smb://"+ipList[i]+"/";
dh= smbc_opendir(ip.toAscii());  // debugger points to this location
if(dh<0)
    return;
emit
        updateTree(i,dh);         // on commenting this line, it still crashes 
}
```

Error:

> talloc: access after free error - first free may be at ../lib/util/talloc_stack.c:103
>     Bad talloc magic value - access after free
>     The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: I suppose there is no shared data, which should cause problem. Anyways, libsmbclient is not a threadsafe library.

Comment: probably there is some global variable being accessed at the same time. If they make no promises of thread safety, you can not assume any. Can you try to use a mutex around the function call?

Comment: It worked, now there are no crashes. But it seems to have defeated the purpose of multi-threading,the speed of scanning is similar to that of using a single thread. Any, idea! smbc_opendir() is perhaps a blocking function, it has induced unwanted serialization.